# Why does running a .sh script from Visual Studio open the file instead of running it?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am attempting to run an .sh script (which itself is supposed to kick off a series of unit tests in flask) from within Visual Studio Code running in Windows 10 and for some reason no matter what I try it only opens the file for editing instead of actually running the file.

This is the exact command I am typing:

```
C:\Users\my.user\MyRepo>.\scripts\run-unit-tests.sh
```

Here are my notes:

1. This is a brand new installation of Windows 10 where I believe I have enabled WSL2
2. I am completely unfamiliar with doing development from within Windows (coming from a Ubuntu/Linux background)
3. My goal is to run this script from within the built in terminal in VS Code, however I have also tried running it from a cmd prompt and also from powershell and both of those also result in opening the file in VS Code.

Addendum: more notes:

I actually have two windows machines.  one is my personal machine, the other provided by my work.  For whatever reason this file works fine on my personal machine but does not on my work machine.  Also the bash script is in a repo which was created by others at my company so i'm certain that this can be made to run without modifying the .sh file itself.

Comment: How are you invoking the script? e.g. what does `bash run-unit-tests.sh` do in WSL2?

Comment: What editor is it opening in? (Is there a default editor associated with `.sh` files, and is Windows interpreting invocation as "open file")

Comment: 1) i am running it exactly as i posted in the question: .\scripts\run-unit-tests.sh   2) if i enter: bash .\scripts\run-unit-tests.sh, or if i run that without the .\ at the beginning i get "no such file or directory"  3) the editor it opens in is Visual Studio Code

Comment: Also i don't understand what you mean by "in WSL2" in your first comment.  am i supposed to run something called WSL2?

Comment: "in WSL2" ::: My bad, my phrasing was vague. I was trying to understand how it worked in Windows Terminal, CMD, or something else (Git Bash here). Glad you got it worked out!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out what was going on.

In windows there are default file associations.  Mine was set up to run Visual Studio Code for the .sh file extension.  Also, windows does not know how to handle .sh files by default.  There were likely many potential fixes for this however the one that worked was for me to re-associate the .sh file extension to open with Git Bash which I happened to also have installed on this machine.

Thanks all who tried to help.